# Xml to table in tsql

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

I have a table which save xml data. The xml is as follows

```
<responses>
  <response>
    <id>UniqueRowID</id>
    <value>16</value>
  </response>
  <response>
    <id>Language</id>
    <value>en-GB</value>
  </response>
  <response>
    <id>UserId</id>
    <value>21</value>
  </response>
</responses>
```

In next column it can have some other data. id & value is common for all. But the some ids in one may not in another row.

Now I need a table in the following format. I know what all columns should show. If some column not present in the xml it can be blank. How can i achieve this?

UniqueRowID     Language   UserId

---             -------    ------

16              en-GB      21

I saw some similar but nothing works for me since xml have different way of representation in those examples

Comment: can you use SSIS? Is this a one time import?

Comment: I'm going to create an ssrs report over the data

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, but i assume if this is a report, then you need to repeatedly load the data. Is SSIS an option?

Comment: I don't have any idea about SSIS (I don't have idea of company having licence also to use the tool). Its not one time work.Every time it need to pull data from database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I place this as second answer as it is a completely different approach. With this code you can read any XML of this structure. Using dynamic SQL makes it possible to create dynamic column names:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTbl (YourXml XML);
INSERT INTO #tmpTbl VALUES
('<responses>
  <response>
    <id>UniqueRowID</id>
    <value>16</value>
  </response>
  <response>
    <id>Language</id>
    <value>en-GB</value>
  </response>
  <response>
    <id>UserId</id>
    <value>21</value>
  </response>
    <response>
    <id>SomeOther1</id>
    <value>SO1</value>
  </response>
    <response>
    <id>SomeOther2</id>
    <value>SO2</value>
  </response>
</responses>');

DECLARE @columnNames VARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    STUFF(
    (
        SELECT ',[' + B.value('id[1]','varchar(max)')+ ']'
        FROM #tmpTbl
        CROSS APPLY YourXml.nodes('/responses/response') AS A(B)
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ),1,1,''    
    )
);

DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)=
'SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT B.value(''id[1]'',''varchar(max)'') AS ColumnName
          ,B.value(''value[1]'',''varchar(max)'') AS ColumnValue
    FROM #tmpTbl
        CROSS APPLY YourXml.nodes(''/responses/response'') AS A(B)
) AS tbl
PIVOT
(
    MIN(ColumnValue) FOR ColumnName IN(' +  @columnNames + ')
) As p';

EXEC(@cmd);
GO

DROP TABLE #tmpTbl;
```

The result:

```
UniqueRowID Language    UserId  SomeOther1  SomeOther2
16          en-GB       21      SO1         SO2
```

Comment: I approched the same way yesterday. Thanks for the updates. I got the data from first answer. That i given pivot

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple XML structure.  If you need to "flatten" it into a SQL table, you can do so with XPATH syntax as shown below.

```
declare @xml xml = '
<responses>
  <response>
    <id>UniqueRowID</id>
    <value>16</value>
  </response>
  <response>
    <id>Language</id>
    <value>en-GB</value>
  </response>
  <response>
    <id>UserId</id>
    <value>21</value>
  </response>
</responses>
';
select
  T.c.value('(id)[1]','nvarchar(100)') as UniqueRowID
 ,T.c.value('(value)[1]','nvarchar(100)') as Language
from
  @xml.nodes('/responses/response') T(c)
```

Which will give you data like this:

```
UniqueRowID | Language
======================
UniqueRowID | 16
Language    | en-GB
UserId      | 21
```

I'm a little confused about what you mean when you write:

*In next column it can have some other data. id & value is common for all. But the some ids in one may not in another row.*

It also seems that you structured this data in a way that isn't really well suited for XML.  Every response element should ideally have the same components.

You might consider something more like this (just food for thought):

```
<responses>
  <response>
    <UniqueRowID>100</UniqueRowID>
    <UserId>16</id>
    <Language>EN-GB</value>
  </response>
  <response>
    <UniqueRowID>200</UniqueRowID>
    <UserId>17</id>
    <Language>ES</value>
  </response>
  <response>
    <UniqueRowID>300</UniqueRowID>
    <UserId>18</id>
    <Language>DE</value>
  </response>
</responses>
```

Comment: Appreciates the effort. But the query will result in 2 columns. I need 3 column result here(If user chooses 3 columns).  In next column it can have some other data means next row may not have userid. Instead it may have sponsorid. If user chooses he is interested in sponsorid,lanuguage only it will show this two columns only as a result

Comment: The data in xml format is good only in my case also. Its actually saving a list of key value pair in the form of id & value

Comment: @BineshNambiarC Do I understand this correctly? You want all `response` nodes to be taken as Key/Value pair with the value as data and the id as column name in one single row? Please check my answer... You might add as many columns as you like. The ones missing will remain empty...

Comment: Thanks both. The issue solved. I worked on the same way. On that day I was working late night. So after seeing the data also i was not thinking of pivoting. Next day i could solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<responses>
  <response>
    <id>UniqueRowID</id>
    <value>16</value>
  </response>
  <response>
    <id>Language</id>
    <value>en-GB</value>
  </response>
  <response>
    <id>UserId</id>
    <value>21</value>
  </response>
</responses>'

SELECT @xml.value('(/responses/response[id="UniqueRowID"]/value)[1]','int') AS UniqueRowID
      , @xml.value('(/responses/response[id="Language"]/value)[1]','varchar(max)') AS Language
      , @xml.value('(/responses/response[id="UserId"]/value)[1]','int') AS UserId
```

The result

```
UniqueRowID Language    UserId
16          en-GB       21
```